# dynamically add audio element with jquery

Tags: jquery, rss

> SO trying to append audio elements for each song pulled from itunes rss feed .All other data populates great but having serious issues with trying to add the audio element dynamically for each song.

```js
 $.get('https://itunes.apple.com/' + countryCode + '/rss/topsongs/limit=3/xml', function(data){
               


               var songArray =$(data).find('entry');

               songArray.each(function(){

                    var title= $(this).find("title").text(); //grab song title
                    var artist= $(this).find("im\\:artist, artist").text(); //grab artist namee
                    var album =$(this).find("im\\:name,name").text(); //grab album name
                    var image=$(this).find("im\\:image,image").eq(2).text(); //grab image link
                    var audioLink=$(this).find("link").eq(1).attr("href"); //grab music file
                    var audio= document.createElement('AUDIO');
                       var source= document.createElement('source');
                     audioLink= '"'+ audioLink + '"'
                    $('source').attr('src', audioLink);
                    $('audio').attr('controls','controls');
                    $('source').attr('type', 'audio/mpeg');
                    
    

          
                    

                      // youtube api
                  // Handle the search button's click event
                        //took the code from the previous assingmet for the youtube api
                          
                          // Set the search term
                          var searchTerm = title;
                          
                          var link;
                      
                          
                          var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=" 
                          + searchTerm + "&part=snippet&maxResults=1&key=AIzaSyBvccDrp39n-InLrjDvv4PH_vfNbN0J_iE";
                        
                          $.getJSON(url, function(data){
                            
                            var id = data.items[0].id.videoId;
                        
                            link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + id;
                              
                                   
                                $("#song").append(


>where i added all the data to be appended to a div on the html         
                            " <br><br>Song :" + title + "<br> Artist :" + artist +  " <br>album: " + album + "<br>" +  "<img src="  + image + "> " +  "<a href= " +  link +  ">"  + link + "</a> <br>" +audio

                                  
                      );

                          });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            var audioLink=$(this).find("link").eq(1).attr("href"); //grab music file
            var audio= document.createElement('AUDIO');
               var source= document.createElement('source');
             audioLink= '"'+ audioLink + '"'
            $('source').attr('src', audioLink); //nothing found! source has not been appended to document
            $('audio').attr('controls','controls');//nothing found! audiohas not been appended to document
            $('source').attr('type', 'audio/mpeg');
```

this code does nothing because audio and source elements has not been appended to document so jquery cant find them.

better try something like:

```
var audio= document.createElement('AUDIO');
audio.setAttribute('controls', true);
var source = document.createElement('source');
source.src = audioLink;

audio.appendChild(source)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('document').ready(function(){
var obj = document.createElement("audio");
        obj.src = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/week7-brrring.m4a";
        obj.volume = 0.1;
        obj.autoPlay = false;
        obj.controls = true;
        obj.play();
});

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```